# How do I make the title field in views as the title of the block?

Tags: 7, views

So how do I make the field "title" also show in the title of the block? Thanks.

Here is the image of the view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyUmo.png

Comment: if its a single list view css can help you.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You generate a list of multiple items in a Views block, which element's title would you like to assign to the block view?

Answer (score 2):

Add a contextual filter of type 'Content: Nid'.
Set 'Provide default value' to 'Content ID from URL'

Under 'When the filter value IS available or a default is provided' set 'Override Title' to %1.

That should do the trick...

Comment: didn't work, that output will be a block, not a page to get the value from. Secondly, how can the nid generate the title of a node?

Comment: Maybe didn't understand what you're trying to do? What is the context of the block and how is it shown? To make the above work, the URL of the page with the block has to provide the title of the node to show in the block... I have to admit, my idea is not quite what you might have been looking for.